# Multiple networks connected.Which is considered?

Tags: networking, internet

Suppose i am connected to two networks-

1. DSL connection.

2.Mobile broadband.

Which one will be considered as the base one and will be used??

Because both do get connected at the same time..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one with a 'better' gateway metric will be chosen.  To find out which one it is, open terminal and type this:

```
route -n
```

I see that I have a gateway with metric 0.0.0.0:

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

So eth0 is my preferred adapter.

Another (probably easier) way to find out is to look at the route to Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8)

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8
```

This is my output:

```
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.0.2 
    cache
```

You can see that it is going via eth0.  Try this on your machine and have a look at the results.

Comment: Thanx a lot..!! This Question was storming my brains from long...!!

Also,is there *absolutely no way* that the connection is shared by both connections??

So that bandwidth increases?? i read a post already here...but just asking that is there *absolutely no way* to do it??

Comment: There is a way to do it, it's referred to as NIC Bonding (I think it has many other synonyms).  I've never done it but there's a help page on the Ubuntu Help Wiki:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding

Comment: Thanx a lot..!! that was helpfull..!! :)